# How can I scroll to google map container div?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

Assume I have button on top of page and I also have google map in bottom of page.
I want to scroll to the map by click on this button. Is it possible?

I wrapped the google map with div and I tried the function "scrollTo" but when I try to get the google map's position with offsetParent it's always null.

Also i'm trying to do that only with javascript (no jquery).

Any idea?

Comment: If you post a (simple) example that does not work, it will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

no JS needed

```
<a name="AnchorName"></a> <--- this is where the anchor name is (place this just above the map)

<a href="#AnchorName">Click here</a> <-- clicking here will take you to where you placed the <a> tag with a name
```

Har you checked out the angular docs? 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: I'm using angular and it doesn't work i already tried this with href.

Comment: Just to be sure; Are you trying to get the page to scroll to the map on the bottom, or the map scrolling up, filling the page? Because HTML anchor links should have no problem what so ever.